# 'in' vs. 'on' for dates

Tags: prepositions, dates

I've met the following phrase:

> Something happened on February 12-25, 2010.

It means that some event started on February 12th and ended on February 25th. Actually the text was about the Olympic Games. Is it correct to use the preposition *on* here? And how should it be pronounced in oral speach?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dates are reported in English as being ***in*** large units like _century, decade, era, epoch, period,_ etc, and also parts of a day -- _morning, afternoon, evening_; ***on*** individual days; and ***at*** individual times, plus _at night_. _The event occurred in the twentieth century, specifically at 03:43 Greenwich, in the early morning on August tenth, in 1952._

Comment: @JohnLawler Oh *that* event. Yes, it was ***over** the weekend, **during** the night, **between** sunset and sunrise. Events **circa** 1950 often were.*

Comment: Oh, there are dozens more, too. But these are the default cases, like _in the book, on the page, at the bottom_.

Comment: For something that spans a period between specific dates or times, we usually use **from** and **to**: _from February 12 to 25, 2010_.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Dates and prepositions with them are a very interesting topic in the English language. But how to pronounce 'from February 12 to 25, 2010'.  I think, 'from the twelfth to twenty-fifth of February in two thousand and ten'?

Answer (score 3):

If you were speaking about the undifferentiated, unsubdivided month of February, you would certainly be well advised (as John Lawler observes in a comment above) to use *in*:

> Something happened in February 2010.

Likewise, if you were speaking somewhat vaguely about the second half of February or the last two weeks of February, *in* (or *during*) would still be the best choice:

> Something happened in [or *during*] the second half of February 2010.

But adding specific dates changes the situation significantly. Idiomatically, we don't say that something happened *in* February 22, 2010; we say that something happened *on* February 22, 2010. Similarly, we don't say that someone's birthday falls *in* Halloween, but *on* Halloween.

The fact that we're dealing in the example sentence with a stretch of 14 days would logically suggest that the "in" form (which is suitable for "the last two weeks of February") would also work here; but idiomatically it doesn't. Instead the specific, single-day endpoints of the specified period change the preposition that a native English speaker is likely to use. For example:

> Something happened during the period from February 12 to February 25, 2010.

(for maximum clarity) or:

> Something happened from February 12 to 25, 2010.

(for brevity, as Barmer says in a comment above) or:

> Something happened on February 12–25, 2010.

(if the words are being telescoped for maximum compression in a news story).